# how to selected audio file path/ Location i Use Intent to chose Audio bt it not show file name

Tags: android

It show path like `/document/audio:38` and if i select from music at time it
show `/external/audio/media/38`

MY audio file name is **Enrique Iglasias - SOMEBODY'S ME**

```
private void selectAudio() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("audio/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Audio"), 1);
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

       if (requestCode == 1) {
          Uri uri = data.getData();
          tvAudioPath.setText(uri.getPath());
          Log.e(TAG, uri.getPath());
       }
    }
}
```